# Using a logical operator for multiple values

Tags: python, dataframe, logical-operators

I want to extract more than one value using logical operators, but so far I couldn't find an easy way to do so. I've tried passing values I want to be excluded as a list but it raised an error. Therefore, this is the way I was able to exclude these values:

```
droppedd = dropped[dropped['date'] == '2021-04-04']
droppedd = droppedd[droppedd['location'] != 'World']
droppedd = droppedd[droppedd['location'] != 'Europe']
droppedd = droppedd[droppedd['location'] != 'North America']
droppedd = droppedd[droppedd['location'] != 'European Union']
droppedd = droppedd[droppedd['location'] != 'South America']
droppedd = droppedd[droppedd['location'] != 'Asia']
```

Droppedd is the name of the output variable. Is there an easier way to exclude these values?

Answer (score 0):

```
droppedd = dropped[dropped['date'] == '2021-04-04']
droppedd = droppedd[droppedd['location'] not in ['World', 'Europe', 'North America' , 'European Union', 'South America', 'Asia' ]]
```

Also dropped is written with one d.

Comment: I know it is but I used dropped for another variable. That's why I used it that  way here.

Comment: Cool motive, still bad practice. Nevertheless, does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Please provide next time an example dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2021-04-04', '2021-04-05', '2021-04-04', '2020-04-04', '2021-05-04', '2021-04-12', '2021-04-12', '2021-04-04'],
                        'location': ['World', 'Europe', 'North America', 'European Union', 'South America', 'Asia', 'Africa', 'Oceania'],
                        'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
                        'y': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
                        'z': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]})


l_keep1= ['2021-04-04']
l_drop2 = ['World', 'Europe', 'North America', 'European Union','South America', 'Asia']

df2 = df1.loc[df1['date'].isin(l_keep1)]
df3 = df2.loc[~df2['location'].isin(l_drop2)]
```